# Replace multiple identical placeholders in a string using an array of values (one at a time)

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace, placeholder

What I want to do is replace the "[replace]" in input string with the corresponding value in the replace array. The total number of values will change but there will always be the same number in the replace array as in input string. I have tried doing this with `preg_replace()` and `preg_replace_callback()`, but I can't get the pattern right for [replace], I also tried using `vsprintf()` but the `%` in `<table width="100%">` was messing it up.

**Replace Array:**

```
$array = array('value 1','value 2','value 3');
```

**Input String**

```
$string = '
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>[replace]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date:</td>
<td>[replace]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Info:</td>
<td>[replace]</td>
</tr>
</table>
';
```

**Desired Result**

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date:</td>
<td>value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Info:</td>
<td>value 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd highly suggest using an HTML parser instead. Not only is it better suited for the task at hand, but it will probably be easier to accomplish the functionality you desire.

Comment: @Amber huh? a parser for this? I think you've misread the question.

Comment: I didn't misread it. Iterating through elements in a parsed DOM tree, manipulating them, and writing them back out would be a much cleaner solution than regex.

Comment: For this demo it would be easier, however the input string comes from a WYSIWYG editor so it completely variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You escape table's `%` with `%%`:

```
$string = <<<EOD
<table width="100%%">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date:</td>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Info:</td>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
</table>
EOD;

$array = array('value 1','value 2','value 3');

echo vsprintf($string, $array);
```

ouput:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date:</td>
<td>value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Info:</td>
<td>value 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks I couldn't find the escape information anywhere and I never had to do it before, do you know of a function that does this?

Comment: I suppose PHP has not bothered to offer a native function to escape `%` with a `%` because typically developers will be manually crafting these placeholder-filled template strings and therefore be able to eyeball any percent symbols which should remain literal.  In your case though, you should move all styling out of the HTML markup and instead populate a CSS stylesheet file. @Scott